# Cannot get child row with DataRowView.CreateChildView

Tags: c#, ado.net

please help me. I don't understand why it does not work:

```
DataRowView copyRow = (DataRowView)medications_ordersBindingSource.Current;
DataView childMedOrdersView = copyRow.CreateChildView(medOrdersDS.Relations["Order_id_fk"]);
MessageBox.Show(childMedOrdersView.Count.ToString()); // return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem.  in my case, it appears to be due to the fact that I have too many columns in my data relation.  It partially works when I reduce the number of join columns (although with too many child records). yet, when I changed it to a single column integer key it did not work.

I started a bug report on MSConnect - 855186